# Skipping over N elements in Prolog List

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am new to Prolog and came across this practice exercise. The questions is asking to define a predicate

```
everyNth(N, List1, List2)
```

such that List2 contains the first item followed by every N'th element item after the first item of List1.

HINT is to use append and length.

For example,

```
everyNth (3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], List2).
List2 = [1,4,7].

everyNth (2, [1,2,3,4,5,6], List2).
List2 = [1,3,5].
```

I approached this problem this way and so far this is all I have:
Not sure If I'm heading in the right direction.

```
 everyNth(N, [], L1).
 everyNth(N, [H|NL], RL) :-
    N > 0,length(NL,N),append(H, NL, RL),everyNth(N,NL,RL).
```

Any suggestions or hints would be greatly helpful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following solution

```
everyNth(_, _, [], []).

everyNth(N, N, [H | Ti], [H | To]) :-
  everyNth(N, 1, Ti, To).

everyNth(N, C, [_ | Ti], Lo) :-
  C < N,
  Cp1 is C+1,
  everyNth(N, Cp1, Ti, Lo).

everyNth(N, Li, Lo) :-
  everyNth(N, N, Li, Lo).
```

I think that you need two use two numbers: the first is `N` and is fixed; the second, `C` is a cointer that start with `1`, reach `N` and start again from `1`; and so on. So the `everyNth/3` clause only call the `everyNth/4` version. Call it with `N` as counter to copy the first element of the input list.

When `C` is equal to `N` (second `everyNth/4`), you copy the header of the input list (`H`) as header of output list; otherwise you throw it away.

You need a terminal clause (`everyNth(_, _, [], []).`) the initualize the output list (to `[]`).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
first_and_every_nth_item( _ , []     , []     ) .  % empty list? Easy!
first_and_every_nth_item( N , [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- % take the first item
  every_nth_item(1,N,Xs,[],Ys)                     % then take every nth item from the remainder.
  .

every_nth_item(_,_,[],Ts,Ys) :-      % if the source list is exhausted, we're good.
  reverse(Ts,Ys)                     % just reverse the accumulator to get the result
  .                                  %
every_nth_item(N,M,[_|Xs],Ts,Ys) :-  % otherwise...
  N < M ,                            % - if N < M 
  N1 is N+1 ,                        % - increment N
  every_nth_item(N1,M,Xs,Ts,Ys)      % - and recurse down, discarding the head of the source list.
  .
 every_nth_item(N,M,[X|Xs],Ts,Ys) :- % otherwise
   N = M ,                           % - if N = M
   T1 = [X|Ts]                       % - prepend X to the accumulator
   every_nth_item(1,M,Xs,T1,Ys)      % - recurse down with the count restarted
   .                                 %
```